# How do you debug php web page that has pretty urls in zend studio?

Tags: php, debugging, url-rewriting

I've read many tutorials on how to debug php web page like [this one](http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/HowToSetupDevelopmentEnvironmentWindows),

all are very good except that I don't see any of them take into account `.htaccess`.

So these solutions won't work for web pages that have pretty urls.

Has anyone figured it out ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at the architecture of the site, and see what framework is being used. Each framework has different routing rules, which deal with the "pretty" urls.